# How to Access Child Element Tag ID

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following setup:

```
<parent>
    <a (click)="getChildId(childId)">
    <child somethingRequired></child>
</parent>
```

And the child template file:

```
<template #childId></template>
```

Can you please guide me what will be the best approach to get the `#childId` and pass it to the `getChildId` function.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer would be to use **`ViewChild`** API in **`ChildComponent`** and **`#localVariable`** in **`ParentCompnent`** as show below,

**DEMO :https://plnkr.co/edit/V8srD4WnlowP8UACNIpI?p=preview**

**child**

```
<input #childId>

export class child {
  @ViewChild('childId') childId:ElementRef;
}
```

**parent**

```
<a (click)="writeValue(has.childId)">GrabValue</a><br>
                       //<<===has variable has an ability to access variables and methods of child component
<child #has></child>                            
       //<<===has is a local variable which can access variables and methods of child component



export class AppComponent {
  source='images/angular.png';
  writeValue(value){
    console.log('parent writeValue');
    console.log(value.nativeElement.value);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked.

I am a bit confused, as I am trying to populate bootstrap pop-up and if the <template> is on the same page, it is working fine.

At the moment the function receives an {Object object}. What should I pass to get the whole html tree? Not sure what is behind the ElementRef.

Comment: Ignore me, it is all working fine now. Thanks again!